# Problem regarding getting address from latlong

Tags: typescript, ionic4

I am using NativeReverseGeocoder for getting the address from lat-long but it gives a response like:

```js
this.nativeGeocoder.reverseGeocode(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude ).then(resp => {
      this.address =  resp[0].locality + " ," + resp[0].subAdministrativeArea + " ," + resp[0].administrativeArea + " ," + resp[0].postalCode + " ," + resp[0].countryName;
    console.log(this.address);
```

```js
this.nativeGeocoder.reverseGeocode(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude ).then(resp => {
      this.address =  resp[0].locality + " ," + resp[0].subAdministrativeArea + " ," + resp[0].administrativeArea + " ," + resp[0].postalCode + " ," + resp[0].countryName;
      console.log("hhjj");
    console.log(this.address);
```

In this `subLocality`, thoroughfare, subThoroughfare are empty fields, can anyone tell me how to get the full address?

Comment: These blocks of code are incomplete

Comment: kindly share the response JSON or specifically the address part.

Comment: I have receive json response like this“countryCode”:“IN”,“countryName”:“India”,“postalCode”:“412308”,“administrativeArea”:“Maharashtra”,“subAdministrativeArea”:“Pune”,“locality”:“Fursungi”,“subLocality”:"",“thoroughfare”:"",“subThoroughfare”:""